# Xcode Error: no such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, jpeg, filepath

I am making a app that shows the solar system and displays a list of the planets and other celestial bodies. Each page for a planet, or other object contains a picture of it. I keep getting a error that tells me that I am missing a image in a folder, when the same image already exists in that folder. This is the error:
***(null): error: /Users/billrandsot/Desktop/Planets/SunDiagram.jpg: No such file or directory***
Im not sure what I should do, but anything is helpful! thanks!

Comment: show your code trying to display that image

Comment: Show that the file exists with a Terminal `pwd` and `ls -la`.

Comment: Sorry Zaph I am new to coding and xcode can you please explain to me what I should do to get there?

Comment: Show the code and the exact error message. Copy from Xcode and paste into the question, you can edit your own question. Understand that the error message is correct so look really hard at your code and the image path. Make sure there are no extra spaces in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your file entension isn't a .png. Also make sure that you don't have any extra spaces or characters. Go to that directory and make sure the file is there.